# Replacing Strings in a column using conditions in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, conditional-statements, updating

I'm new to the SSIS. Here is what I'm trying to do. I have an Excel source with a column with different types of food (ex. beef, apples, carrots etc.) and I'd like to update them to more generic types:

```
1. beef, chicken -> meat 
2. apples, organes -> fruits
```

etc.

I was trying Replace in Derived Column and OLE DB Command but I have a feeling there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Did it work? if it works and you can maintain it, it's a pretty good start. Personally I would do it all in the database with a select case but if you want to do it in SSIS, the only other way is to use a lookup

Comment: I gave up on using replace. I managed to get it to work with OLE DB. In the end I realized some things or better done on DB than in ETL :)

Comment: Next time please post what you did and the error message otherwise no one has any idea how to help. IMHO, most things are better done in DB than ETL but that's just my preference